Command mode not working in Jupyter notebook, but fine in Jupyter lab
Just installed Jupyter and I can escape out of cells into command mode and use the regular shortcuts just fine in Jupyter Lab. However, in Jupyter notebook, the commands are not accepted. For example, escaping out of a cell and hitting ctrl+a selects all of the browser text and not the cells.
I get exactly the same behaviour in Firefox and Chrome, so it doesn't seem to be a browser specific or OS level intercept of the keystrokes. Similarly, it seems strange that it works fine in Lab and not Notebook.
FWIW I'm running Fedora 40 with GNOME 46
jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.23.0
ipykernel        : 6.29.3
ipywidgets       : not installed
jupyter_client   : 7.4.9
jupyter_core     : 5.1.0
jupyter_server   : 2.12.5
jupyterlab       : 4.1.0
nbclient         : 0.9.0
nbconvert        : 7.16.0
nbformat         : 5.9.2
notebook         : 7.0.7
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.14.1

Anyone understand what happening here? There seems to be another individual with the same issue based on this answer from a few years ago.

I think you want maybe 7.1.3? There was an issue with command mode in version(s) around the time of yours, I think, based on here. Unfortunately, that post doesn't specify a specific bug report and so I cannot be sure if it is a perfect match to yours. I see here and here which seem perhaps encompassing what you report?
